# Use different adapter for LG 25UM65-p

Tags: adapter, monitor

My LG monitor (25UM65-P) has original adapter (19V, 1.7Amp), can I use a different adapter (14V, 2.14Amp) for it? Has this any side effects or negative points?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the current available @ 2.14A is high enough - the voltage at 14v will be too low and it will likely not work.

If connected correctly it is unlikely (but still possible) to cause damage though since it is a lower voltage. If the connector is wired incorrectly however it will probably fry it in short order and could pose a safety risk.

So if you aren't sure what you are doing I would not recommend trying this.